# How to use @Scripts in MVC3 VS10 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3 application in Visual Studio 2010 . I need to refer the scripts/styles in layout page using following tag

```
@System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/script")
```

But I am unable to use like this, since System.web,optimization is not available from _Layout.cshtml( even though the dll is referred in the project).Please refer to below image

[image]

[image]

how to resolve this?

Comment: Add this `@using System.Web.Optimization` namespace in `_Layout.cshtml`

Comment: System.web.optimization is not available in _layout page, so i cannot include this namespace

Comment: Do you have this ` System.Web.Optimization.dll` reference in your web project?

Comment: yes, it is referred.

Comment: Then you can directly add `@using System.Web.Optimization` in your `_Layout.cshtml`.

Comment: What error are you getting while building your project

Comment: Try register your script/style bundles in Global.asax like `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);` and add `@using System.Web.Optimization` in your layout page. I'll post detailed answer if you want more details.

Comment: I have followed the steps mentioned in this link http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/0a9M050113-Bundling-and-minification-in-MVC3-and-Asp.Net-4.0.html. But it won't work

Comment: Can you show the screenshot from references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` using Package Manager Console using below command.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

Next you need to reference the dll `System.Web.Optimization.dll` in your web project then you can add this namespace `@using System.Web.Optimization in your`_Layout.cshtml`.

Also make sure `System.Web.Optimization.dll` is present in bin folder in project.

Comment: I have referred the dll but unable to use it in layout

Comment: @user3610920 Does this dll exists in bin folder `System.Web.Optimization.dll`

Answer (score 0):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

In the Nuget Package Manager Console.

Comment: I have added the dll via NuGet only.